# Photochromism time of colour change

Tags: photochemistry, light

I know there are chemical pigments/dyes which produce an immediate reversible colour change in UV or direct sunlight. Is there a way to postpone the colour change so that it does not happen immediately but rather over a period of 30 minutes for example? Would it have to do with the concentration of dye or is it the chemicals themselves which have different colour change times.

Comment: Older photochromic glasses (the ones that went grey in sunlight) were pretty slow in changing, particularly when cold. I have no idea what changed over the years to speed them up.

Comment: @jonCuster they probably found better chemicals to use.